# devise user under nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a resource called "Store" that can have many accounts registered, but how im supposed to do this using device? i've setup this

```
class Store
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account
  belongs_to :store
end

Panel::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :stores do
    devise_for :accounts
  end
end
```

but im getting

```
Showing panel/app/views/accounts/registrations/new.html.haml where line #2 raised:
undefined method `account_registration_path' for #<Module:0x007f9a67940918>
```

This is bc its expecting something like "account_store_registration_path" but where all this logic goes

rake routes output

```
account_store_password POST   /accounts/stores/:store_id/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#create
         new_account_store_password GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/password/new(.:format)                             devise/passwords#new
        edit_account_store_password GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/password/edit(.:format)                            devise/passwords#edit
                                     PATCH  /accounts/stores/:store_id/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#update
                                     PUT    /accounts/stores/:store_id/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#update
  cancel_account_store_registration GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/cancel(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#cancel
         account_store_registration POST   /accounts/stores/:store_id(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#create
     new_account_store_registration GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/sign_up(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#new
    edit_account_store_registration GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/edit(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#edit
                                     PATCH  /accounts/stores/:store_id(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#update
                                     PUT    /accounts/stores/:store_id(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#update
                                     DELETE /accounts/stores/:store_id(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#destroy
         account_store_confirmation POST   /accounts/stores/:store_id/confirmation(.:format)                             devise/confirmations#create
     new_account_store_confirmation GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/confirmation/new(.:format)                         devise/confirmations#new
                                     GET    /accounts/stores/:store_id/confirmation(.:format)                             devise/confirmations#show
```

Comment: Where is `account_registration_path` referenced? Do you have a `RegistrationController`?

Comment: sorry, it was "devise_for :accounts"

Comment: what is the output of your `rake routes` command?

Answer (score 0):

So to accomplish this i did something very simple

I define an additional route for the account:

```
Panel::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :accounts

  resources :stores do
    resources :accounts
  end
end
```

I generated an accounts controller and views, and used the Devise generated model. So I used the new controller to create accounts and the devise helpers to manage the login logic.

So now i can have Accounts that belongs to an store